# Proving the existence of a sequence of polynomials convergent to a continuous function $f$.

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, uniform-convergence

I need to show that if $f$ is continuous function ($f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), then there exists a sequence of polynomials which converges to $f$ on *any* compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I would appreciate any help/direction ...

Comment: Would this be true if we add "uniformly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon_n = 1/n$.

Let $A_n$ be the closed interval $[-n,n]$.

Let $S$ be any compact set.

For each $\epsilon_n$, the [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) states that there exists a polynomial $P_n(x)$ such that for any $x \in A_n$, $$|f(x) - P_n(x)| < \epsilon_n$$

The fact that $S$ is compact allows us to apply the [Heine-Borel Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem), which implies that $S$ is closed and bounded. The fact that $S$ is bounded means that for sufficiently large $n$, $S \subset A_n$.

You should now be able to prove that this sequence of polynomials $P_n$ converges to $f$ on $S$, using the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \epsilon_n = 0$$

Comment: in Weierstrass Approximation Theorem, there is a close interval, how we can claim it is true for any compact set?

Comment: @erfansoheil I've edited my answer to include the use of [Heine-Borel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem) to show that the compact set $S$ must be closed and bounded. A closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{R}$ is simply a closed interval.

Comment: yes, $S$ must be close and bounded, but why by conditions of  Weierstrass Approximation Theorem $S$ must be a close interval, is any compact set in $\mathbb R$ is close interval ?

Comment: no, because $\{a_n\} \cup \{0\}$ is compact, bounded and closed but it is not closed interval

Comment: Thanks, But what I believe you're showing is that for any S, exist a uniformly convergent sequence, But is there a sequence that is uniformly convergent in any S?

Comment: sorry, i mean $\{\frac{1}{n}\}\cup \{0\}$

Comment: @John If you want that you can have the interval expand as epsilon decreases: Use the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem to find a $P_n(x)$ that is at most $\epsilon_n$ away from $f$ in the closed interval $[-n, n]$. Then the limit of the sequence whose terms are $P_n(x)$ is clearly $f(x)$, in any closed and bounded interval (because any closed and *bounded* interval is included in $[-n,n]$ for sufficiently large $n$).

Comment: @erfansoheil You're right. You could have used $\{0,1\}$ for simplicity, but you are correct either way. EDIT: the method that I outlined in the comment above this one works regardless of the closed interval thing.

Comment: you're right, many thanks!

Comment: yes, it's correct, thank you for your chating

Comment: Would this still be true if we add "uniformly?"